# How to connect the points with a line in scatter plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot COVID-19 infections in Turkey with a scatter plot graph using ggplot2. However, I couldn't connect the points with a connecting line. I've searched a lot but couldn't draw a line no matter what I did.

Here is my code.

```
    library(ggplot2)

Date <- c("11/03","12/03","13/03","14/03","15/03","16/03")
Infected <- c(1,1,5,6,18,47)

Covid_19 <- data.frame(Date,Infected)

pl <- ggplot(Covid_19,aes(x=Date, y=Infected))

pl3 <- pl + geom_point(aes(color = 'blue'), size=5) + geom_line() + ggtitle("COVID-19 in Turkey")

print(pl3)
```

I tried to use geom_line() function but I get a warning and the line doesn't show up.

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
>   adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: Your dates are just strings—do you want actual date objects?

Comment: Sure, that would be good.

Comment: Yes, it does. However, I found the answer thanks to carlos siri's answer. I accepted his answer. Thank you a lot!

Comment: So that's actually an automated comment—I flagged your question as a duplicate of that one. We try to limit how many questions are on the site that already have answers. If you think that one has you covered, you have the option to [mark it as a duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296481/5325862), which doesn't discredit the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not grouping your lines by variables. You should change the group aesthetic.

```
pl <- ggplot(Covid_19,aes(x=Date, y=Infected, group = 1))
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you a lot!